# how is window.onload working? what is difference between calling a function on it and assigning value to it

Tags: javascript

Say there is a function

```
function init(){
    alert ('hello there')
}

window.onload = init;
```

Here why is't not `init()` but `init` when we are actually **calling** the `init` function when the page loads

Comment: `init()` means "call the function right now". `init` means "this is the function I'm talking about." This is fairly basic JavaScript syntax/semantics so you might want to consider going through some introductory tutorials.

Comment: Keep in mind that we **are not** calling the function at the time `window.onload = init;` is executed. What that does is passing the reference of the function to the browser, so that the browser will execute it for you.

Comment: thanks Pointy and Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last line, you are actually assigning the "init" function object to the "onload" member of the "window" object.

When a page finishes loading, the browser tries to execute whatever value is stored in the "onload" member of the window object. It is presumed that this will be a function. Your code defines a function called "init" with the specified behavior of throwing an alert message. Then it assigns this function to be the "onload" function that the browser calls when the page loads.

If you wanted to execute the "init" function yourself, you would use the "init();" syntax.